# Maven MojoExecutionException occurs while building project

Tags: java, maven

I'm facing this issue, when I'm deploying my application using Maven, please suggest some solution.

Error log

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.1.0:xsdtojava (generate-xsd-sources) on project coin-model: Could not create runtime jar: The system cannot find the path specified -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.1.0:xsdtojava (generate-xsd-sources) on project coin-model: Could not create runtime jar
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not create runtime jar
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.runForked(AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.java:509)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.run (http://org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.run)(AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.java:342)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.execute(AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.java:238)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2070)
        at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.runForked(AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.java:465)
        ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

the path of the jar provided might be incorrect.